# On a Lagrange remainder application.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Suppose I have $f(x)$ where $f$ is three times continuously differentiable.

Then from the Lagrange form of the remainder 
   $ R_k(x) = \frac{f^{(k+1)}(c)}{(k+1)!} (x-x_0)^{k+1} $

I have $$f(x) - f(x_0) = f'(c) (x-x_0)$$

for some $|c| \le |x|$ and taking $k = 1$. Is this the same as the mean value theorem?

In my notes I wrote that there exists a $\lambda$ s.t. $$f(x) - f(x_0) = f'(x_0-\lambda(x-x_0)) (x-x_0)$$

where  $\lambda \in [0,1]$ and $x \in N(x_0)$ (a neighbourhood of $x_0$).

But I am having difficulties proving that $|x_0-\lambda(x-x_0)| < |x|$, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The correct is $c=x_0-\lambda (x_0-x)$ for some $\lambda \in (0,1)$.

Comment: @Tomás Thanks, could I have a reference for a proof?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder

Comment: @Tomás thanks again but I meant of the correction you stated. Why does it work?

Comment: Read the wikipedia article that I have cited above.

Comment: $\{ x_0 + \lambda (x-x_0) : \lambda \in (0,1) \}$ is exactly the set of numbers between $x_0$ and $x$. Usually I don't bother writing this out formally, because you don't know whether $x>x_0$ or $x<x_0$, so you can't use interval notation. So I just say "$c$ is between $x_0$ and $x$".